# Unable to access bitbucket repository on macos

Tags: git, ssl-certificate

Suddenly SourceTree(on mac) started giving below error
fatal: unable to access : SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect.
Have updated Current version of openssl to: OpenSSL 1.1.1g
But still facing the same issue.

Comment: You might want to re-generate that key.

Answer (score 1):

Try and regenerate key, [adding them to your BitBucket profile setting page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/ssh-user-keys-for-personal-use-776639793.html)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

See if by using those new keys, the issue persists.